# Cant Fetch CoreData Attribute Value When UITableView Is Empty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app that adds the amount 5 to my core data attribute value every time the swipe to delete tableviewcell function is used. The Core Data configuration looks like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YR6.png The code in the commit editingStyle class looks like:

```
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Goal> = Goal.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let array_users = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            let user = array_users[0]
            var count: Int64 = user.value(forKey: "totalGold") as! Int64
            count += 5
            user.setValue(count, forKey: "totalGold")
            let str = String(describing: user.value(forKey: "totalGold") as! Int64)
            totalGold.text = str
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } catch {

            }

             }

            catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
            }
let managedObject: NSManagedObject = controller.object(at: indexPath) as NSManagedObject;
        context.delete(managedObject)
        ad.saveContext()
    }
}
```

Then I use the same fetching process in viewDidLoad, like so:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Goal> = Goal.fetchRequest()
    do {

        let array_users = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        let user = array_users[0]
        let count: Int64 = user.value(forKey: "totalGold") as! Int64
        user.setValue(count, forKey: "totalGold")
        let str = String(describing: user.value(forKey: "totalGold") as! Int64)
        totalGold.text = str




        //save the context
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }

        } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
```

This code works fine for every case unless there are no table view cells in the table view. Then, when I try to reload the view while there are no cells, i get an index out of range error while trying to fetch on the line :

```
 let user = array_users[0]
```

Obviously, this is due to the fact that when I try to fetch the latest value for totalGold, it can't find it and it thinks theres no values, so I'm doing the fetching wrong.  How do I properly fetch the latest attribute value for totalGold?

Answer (score 0):

you can put those in the condition

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Goal> = Goal.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let array_users = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if array_users.count > 0 {
            let user = array_users[0]
            let count: Int64 = user.value(forKey: "totalGold") as! Int64
            user.setValue(count, forKey: "totalGold")
            let str = String(describing: user.value(forKey: "totalGold") as! Int64)
            totalGold.text = str

            //save the context
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } catch {
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: For some reason this does not solve the issue.  Now when the view loads, the totalGold attribute value is reset and the text label reads "0" like its default value.